# How to get a Wallet from a mnemonic phrase?

Tags: javascript, web3js, ethers.js

I need to migrate a project from ethers.js to web3js, but I can't find any clear documentation on how to use web3js with mnemonic phrases. For example:

```
const provider = new StaticJsonRpcProvider(process.env.RPC_URL);

const wallet = Wallet.fromMnemonic(mnemonic).connect(provider);
                       ^^^^^^^^^^ equivalent in web3.js???
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[web3js](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/) currently (v1.8) doesn't support generating private keys from mnemonic.

As a workaround, you can use Truffle's [hdwallet-provider](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@truffle/hdwallet-provider) that accepts a mnemonic and an RPC URL.

```
const HDWalletProvider = require("@truffle/hdwallet-provider");
const Web3 = require("web3");

let provider = new HDWalletProvider({
    mnemonic: {
        phrase: "test test test test test test test test test test test junk"
    },
    providerOrUrl: "https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/<your_api_key>"
});

const web3 = new Web3(provider);
```

Comment: thanks. So for every ocasion where I use mnemonic with ethers I need to use this truffle wallet provider ?